# Best way to optimize timer queue with concurrent_priority_queue C++

Tags: c++, concurrency

I'm working on timer queue using `concurrent_priority_queue` right now..

I implemented basic logic of executing most urgent event in this queue.

Here's my code.

```
TimerEvent ev{};
while (timer.mLoop)
{
    while (timer.mQueue.empty() == false)
    {
        if (timer.mQueue.try_pop(ev) == false)
            continue;

        if (ev.Type == EVENT_TYPE::PHYSICS) // Physics event is around 15 ~ 17ms
        {
            auto now = Clock::now();            
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(ev.StartTime - now);
            timer.mGameServerPtr->PostPhysicsOperation(ev.WorldID);
        }
        else if (ev.Type == EVENT_TYPE::INVINCIBLE) // This event is 3sec long.
        {
            auto now = Clock::now();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(ev.StartTime - now); // This is wrong!!
            timer.mGameServerPtr->ReleaseInvincibleMode(ev.WorldID);
        }
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
}
```

The problem would be easily solved if there is like `front`/`top` method in `concurrent_priority_queue`.

But there is no such method in class because it isn't thread-safe.

So, I just popped event out of the queue and waited until start time of the event.
In this way, I shouldn't have to insert event into queue again.

But problem is that if I have another type of event like `EVENT_TYPE::INVINCIBLE`, then I shouldn't just use `sleep_for` because this event is almost 3 second long. While waiting for 3 second, the `PHYSICS` event will not executed in time.

I can use `sleep_for` method for `PHYSIC` event since it is most shortest one to wait.
But I have to re-insert `INVINCIBLE` event into queue.

How can I optimize this timer without re-insert event into queue again?

Comment: I prefer to push the processes in a task-queue, to be processed separately by a task thread, to keep the internal timer light weight and avoid possible delays.

Comment: @seccpur Do you mean that if I have 3 different event, then I should use 3 different thread?

Comment: A single executor thread can manage the tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I optimize this timer without re-insert event into queue again?

By the looks of it, that'll be hard when using the implementation of `concurrent_priority_queue` you are currently using. It wouldn't be hard if you just used the standard `std::priority_queue` and added some locking where needed though.

Example:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>

using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;

struct TimerEvent {
    void operator()() { m_event(); }

    bool operator<(const TimerEvent& rhs) const {
        return rhs.StartTime < StartTime;
    }

    time_point StartTime;
    std::function<void()> m_event; // what to execute when the timer is due
};

class TimerQueue {
public:
    ~TimerQueue() { shutdown(); }
    void shutdown() {
        m_shutdown = true;
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

    // add a new TimerEvent to the queue
    template<class... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args) {
        std::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);

        m_queue.emplace(TimerEvent{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

    // Wait until it's time to fire the event that is first in the queue
    // which may change while we are waiting, but that'll work too.
    bool wait_pop(TimerEvent& ev) {
        std::unique_lock lock(m_mutex);

        while(!m_shutdown &&
              (m_queue.empty() || Clock::now() < m_queue.top().StartTime))
        {
            if(m_queue.empty()) { // wait "forever"
                m_cv.wait(lock);
            } else { // wait until first StartTime
                auto st = m_queue.top().StartTime;
                m_cv.wait_until(lock, st);
            }
        }
        if(m_shutdown) return false; // time to quit

        ev = std::move(m_queue.top()); // extract event
        m_queue.pop();

        return true;
    }

private:
    std::priority_queue<TimerEvent> m_queue;
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    std::atomic<bool> m_shutdown{};
};
```

If an event that is due before the event we're currently waiting for in `wait_pop` comes in, the `m_cv.wait`/`m_cv.wait_until` will unblock (because of the `m_cv.notify_all()` in `emplace()`) and that new element will be the first in queue.

The event loop could simply be:

```cpp
void event_loop(TimerQueue& tq) {
    TimerEvent te;
    while(tq.wait_pop(te)) {
        te(); // execute event
    }
    // the queue was shutdown, exit thread
}
```

And you could put any kind of invocable with the time point when you'd like it to fire in that queue.

```cpp
#include <thread>

int main() {
    TimerQueue tq;

    // create a thread to run the event loop
    auto ev_th = std::thread(event_loop, std::ref(tq));

    // wait a second
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    // add an event in 5 seconds
    tq.emplace(Clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(5), [] {
        std::cout << "second\n";
    });

    // wait a second
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    // add an event in 2 seconds
    tq.emplace(Clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(2), [] {
        std::cout << "first\n";
    });

    // sleep some time
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    // shutdown, only the event printing "first" will have fired
    tq.shutdown();
    ev_th.join();
}
```

[Demo with logging](https://godbolt.org/z/8eWMx3M7G)

Comment: So, I can solve it using locks.. or I can build my own lock-free priority queue but it would be very difficult..

Comment: @Tomson _"So, I can solve it using locks"_ - Yes, the two implementations of `concurrent_priority_queue` I've looked at does not support waiting with the `pop` until the time has come for the first item in the queue so I'd make a queue like the one in this answer that does. _"or I can build my own lock-free priority queue"_ - None of the `concurrent_priority_queue` implementations I've looked at claim to be lock-free, so unless you notice a real performance degradation when creating your own queue that supports what you need, I would go for that.